# BigQuery Join tables based on condition

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

**Table No 1:**

[image]

**Table No 2:**

[image]

**Result**

[image]

```
 I have 2 Table :
    In table 1 column Name is unique identifier and also in Table 2 column Name is unique identifier 

Based on Table 2 ,column : Name I want to get data from Table 1 then I want to map the column tags on which date it is applied in Table2 column Date. 
As in table 2 , column : name , value :ghi , Date : 2/4/2022 tag was applied but in table 1 we have a cost for 2/1/2022 and 2/4/2022. so in result i will say on 2/1/2022 (no set) and after we give its value.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so you can use a query like below

```
select 
t1.date, 
t1.Name, 
t1.cost,
IFNULL(t2.tags,'(not set)')
 from table1 t1 left outer join
table2 t2 on t1.name=t2.name and t1.date>=t2.date
```